# De una consulta MySQL con PHP acotada, Fecha desde fecha hasta, agrupar campos repetidos y sumarlos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo una tabla de gastos que sus columnas son:

```
Id_gasto, fecha_gasto, cuenta_contable,monto_gasto.
```

Con el script que copio mas abajo logro agrupar todos los gastos a traves de su cuenta contable y sumarlos, esto funciona bien.

Ahora lo que necesito y no puedo lograr es acotar esta búsqueda a una determinada fecha. Probé agregarle:

`WHERE fecha_gasto BETWEEN '$fecha_desde.00:00:00' AND '$fecha_hasta.23:59:59'`

Pero me arroja un error.

```
<body>

<?php
                if ($_POST['fecha_desde'] =="") { $fecha_desde='1111-11-11';} else {$fecha_desde=$_POST['fecha_desde'];}
                if ($_POST['fecha_hasta'] =="") { $fecha_hasta='9999-12-31';} else {$fecha_hasta=$_POST['fecha_hasta'];}

                include 'abrir_conexion.php';
                $query = "SELECT destino_gasto, cuenta_contable_gasto,id_concepto_gasto, descripcion_gasto, sum(monto_gasto) as sumaGasto
                FROM gastos g
                INNER JOIN i_gasto_contable ON (g.cuenta_contable_gasto=i_gasto_contable.id_concepto_gasto)
                WHERE destino_gasto='1' AND ingreso_egreso='g' GROUP BY cuenta_contable_gasto ORDER BY descripcion_gasto ASC" or die ("Ha fallado la conexión F3");
                $consulta = $conexion->query($query);

                echo' 
                <div class="p-1 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white"><h5> <center>Gastos y aprotes compartidos</center> </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap  table-sm">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="font-size:15px" width ="30%">Cuenta Contable</th>                        
                                <th style="font-size:15px" width ="15%">Gasto</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>';
                            while ( $registro = $consulta -> fetch_assoc() ) {

                        echo'
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size:15px">'.$registro['descripcion_gasto'].'</td>
                                <td style="font-size:15px">'.number_format("{$registro['sumaGasto']}", 2, ",", ".").'</td>
                            </tr>';     
                            }
                        echo'                               
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><strong>Total</strong></td>

                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>    
                </div>';
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál error? Proporciona más información.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado Triby, muchas gracias por tu interes, pude encontrar el error, el cual era que ponia en el selec fecha_gasto, esto hacia que arroje un error en la linea del while, agregue esta linea WHERE fecha_gasto BETWEEN '$fecha_desde.00:00:00' AND '$fecha_hasta.23:59:59' y funciona perfecto